# Files disappear on 10.04

Tags: 10.04, ext4

For the second time I experienced a strange behaviour on my Ubuntu 10.04 box: some files are disappearing.

The first time happened with a NTFS partition on an external usb disk: "disk utility" told me that it had bad sectors in it and thus it was unreadable but, after a reformat of the disk, it was recognized succesfully.

The last time it happened with a ext4 partition: my home folder was almost completely wiped out; fortunately enough I use to store backups of my files, so I restored them but I can't figure out why I'm encountering those kind of situations.

So I assume that the problem is not really a matter of bad sectors (two different hard disks, that after the restore are working fine).

What am I supposed to do in order to debug/resolve the issue?

NOTE: the OS is a former Ubuntu Studio 9.10, upgraded to 10.04.

Comment: Open a console and run `badblocks` as well as `fsck.ext4`. Do those programs report errors?

Comment: Run a memory test. Mysterious crashes and filesystem corruption can be symptoms of bad RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/591532 can be related with your problem, I was having a issue with kernel 2.35.14 it seemed like my hd had stoped to work but the problem was the kernel bug that I solved by upgrading it.